# Are there any security risks using subjects in Angular this way?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subject

Everytime I have to use a variable in different components which can be changed over time, I store that variable in a service and wrap the value in a Subject such that every component register changes when next is called.
But then I see tutorials where it is mentioned that one has to be careful when using subjects. They do the following:

```
// in some service
private subject$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
subjectAsObservable: Observable<any> = this.subject$.asObservable();
```

and then the observable is used in the components but then I would not be able to call `next` to emit new values.

Is there any risk when using subject the following way:

```
// in some service
subject$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

and then subscribe to that subject in the components and if components make changes to the variable, `next` is called and every component that subscribes to that subject gets the new value.

Is the following implementation different (more "secure") to the implementation above:

```
private subject$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

emitNewValue(value: any): void {
    this.subject$.next(value);
}

getSubject(): Subject<any> {
    return this.subject$:
}
```

I do not quite get the security risks. How would I deal correctly with subjects?

Comment: what does typecontrol has to do with security?

Comment: @Antoniossss I don't know, I watched some tutorials and sometimes I hear such things and I do not quite get it , that is why I am asking this question

Comment: But what do you hear exactly?

Comment: @Antoniossss For example that subjects should not be accessable directly in components

Comment: Its rather about clean code, not risks of any kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about encapsulation. In larger applications, it is a good idea to have only one place that emits to the shared stream (subject), which is in the service.

Then no other component can, for example, accidentally call `complete()` on the subject. In the service, just provide one method in order to emit (emitNewValue in your example). A getter for the subject is not needed as exposing the subject with `asObservable` provides components with a read-Only copy of the subject, which they can listen/subscribe to.

Comment: @Invader  Did you check that out?

Comment: Everything you wrote in that comment

Comment: @Antoniossss You are right, I did a mistake. Thank you both for the clarification!